# pandas-profiling / ydata-profiling : not able disable some basic alerts like "Zeros"

Tags: python, validation, pandas-profiling

I'm using ydata-profiling (pandas profiling) and I'm not able to disable some alerts (e.g. Zeros).

Here, https://ydata-profiling.ydata.ai/docs/master/pages/advanced_usage/available_settings.html , I can find only some alerts which can be removed, for example correlations, but not Zeros as an example.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to disable some of the alerts such as Zeros or Infinite.
The one's covered in the documentation are the warnings that are possible to configure or turn-off.

You can always send an Feature request: https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/issues